iptables redirect interface on certain ports
I have the following problem. I have a server (subnet x.x.x.x) with a OpenConnect-client (tun0) on it. It redirects all traffic for a subnet (y.y.y.y) to another server (split-tunnel). But now I am also in this subnet (y.y.y.y) and if I try to connect to my server (x.x.x.x) it will redirect all answers over the VPN and not to me. I tried to make an iptables entry to send all requests with source ports a,b,c to eth0 so I could get the response. But I was not successful.
This is what I tried:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d y.y.y.y/16 -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports a,b,c -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A OUTPUT -d y.y.y.y/16 -p tcp -m multiport --sports a,b,c -j MASQUERADE

Network diagram
y.y.y.y:eth0 ---request---> x.x.x.x ---response---> y.y.y.y:tun0

Maybe someone has an idea how to solve this.

This is really hard to understand with all the letters, can you use real numbers?
